# JQuery fadeIn() moving other CSS elements on fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I've just been learning some jQUery to get a basic image gallery going on a website I'm creating for a hotel but it's currently not going to plan. I've got it so the arrows will cycle through images (no animation yet) but I decided that the arrows should fade in when the image is hovered over and fade out when not but this is messing up the CSS somehow.

The arrows start faded out by calling: `$('.arrowRight').fadeOut(0);$('.arrowLeft').fadeOut(0);`

at the start of the jQuery ready() function.

This is fine, but when you hover over the image and the arrows fade in, the image shifts to the right and I don't know why. I suppose it could be because the left arrow now fading in means it is getting pushed over by it but the arrow has the following css:

```
position:relative;
top: -90px;
left: 25px;
```

Should a relative element be able to alter a normal element's position?

If you need to try it out, just hover over the large (placeholder) image and they image will jump across when the arrows fade in and jump back when they fade out.

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm a jQuery noob.

Here is a link to the page: [BeanSheaf Hotel Temporary Space](http://www.pentathlongb-yorkshire.co.uk/tomsmith/Beansheaf/v3/hotel.html)

Thanks for your time,

InfinitiFizz

Comment: You may want to check out the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and thanks for showing me how much I need to learn :)

It's working now using the suggestions basically everyone said, about making the container relative and the arrows absolute. Now I just have to work out how to carry over events after using replaceWith() yay.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: One more question sorry, I have now updated the page (changing the CSS in fund.css and some jQuery in gallery.js so that events are delegated when the image inside the gallery is changed). The hovering works perfectly in terms of the elements not jumping around but my problem now is that the arrows will fade back out on hoverOut above and below #imageContainer but not to the left or right of it. Also, the fading in and out of arrowRight seems to be messing up Internet Explorer's rendering of it, but arrowLeft looks fine, any ideas?

Sorry if I should have asked this in a new question.

Thanks

Comment: Wont this interfere with a centered page... .. because when you resize browser window the absolutely positioned divs will shift position to the left or right depending on larger or smaller window size .. ?

Comment: Are you trying to answer the original question? If you are, please clarify your answer a bit more. If not, you should make a comment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#imageContainer` should have: `position:relative`

`arrowLeft` should have:

```
position:absolute;
top:90px;
left:5px;
```

Relatively-positioned elements take up space in your layout. Since your arrows were relatively positioned they bump things around when they appear.

In order to position things so this doesn't happen, the items "on top" of the image need to be positioned absolutely. This means they are no longer part of the flow of the layout but are "on top" of it.

Absolutely-positioned items need a point of reference for the point of origin (0,0). These items look at their wrapper and go up the HTML tree until they find the first relatively-positioned element to determine their origin point. If there is none, it uses the `<body>` as the point of reference.

Because we are adding `position:relative` to `imageContainer`, the container now becomes the point of reference, allowing you to accurately position your arrows using `top:` and `left:`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method assigns `none` to the `display` property of the element.
try to change the target element's `position` to `absolute` wrapped by a `relative` positioned element.

> *The `.fadeOut()` method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.
>
>   -- [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the hyperlink surrounding the image is what is pushing everything to the right when it fades in.  Try applying the styles to that instead of the image itself.

I'd suggest getting firebug if you don't use it already, makes determining why something is happening much easier.

Edit:
Actually it's more than just that.  Throw position relative on imageContainer, and make the hyperlink position absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You doing all wrong dude :) You need to do this:

1) `position:relative` for `#imageContainer`

2) `position:absolute` for `arrorLeft` and `arrowRight` parents (so for links) and try to play with them with `left` and `top`.

After you do this, you won't have any problem with jumping stuff on page :)